# Consulta rango de fechas mysql

Tags: javascript, html, python

Tengo en html un formulario con una tabla que se trae informacion de una base de datos. hay dos input para fecha y un botos que manda a una funcion de javascrip. el codigo scrip es este:

```
async function buscar() {

var datos = {
    "txtFecha1":document.getElementById('txtFecha1').value,
    "txtFecha2":document.getElementById('txtFecha2').value
}
var url = URLSERVIDOR + 'listado/consulta'
fetch(url, {
    "method": 'POST',
    "body": JSON.stringify(datos),
    "headers":{
    "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    }
})
```

se supone que asta aqui mando las fechas a la consulta en python
y esta otra parte me devuelve los datos para mostrarlos en una tabla en html

```
var url = URLSERVIDOR + 'listado/consulta'
var respuesta = await fetch(url, {
    "method": 'GET',
    "headers":{
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    }
})     
listado = await respuesta.json();
var html = ''
for (registro of listado) {
    
    var row = `<tr>
    <td>${registro.folio}</td>
    <td>${registro.lote}</td>
    <td>${registro.tabla}</td>
    <td>${registro.cajas}</td>
    <td>${registro.peso_neto}</td>
    </tr>`
        html = html + row;
}
document.querySelector('#tablaFechas> tbody').outerHTML = html
}
```

ahora el codigo python es este:

```
@app.route('/api/listado/consulta',methods = ['POST','GET'])
@cross_origin()
def tablaFechas():
if request.method == 'POST':
    txtFecha1 = (request.json['txtFecha1'])
    txtFecha2 = (request.json['txtFecha2'])
    print(txtFecha2)
    print(txtFecha1)
```

asta aqui funciona bien por que me imprime los valores que le estoy dando en el html
cuando continua me devuelve los datos a la tabla en el html, funciona pero me da una serie de errores, ahora la intencion es mandar esos datos de la fecha en la consulta en la base de datos y sustituir los valores que tengo esquitos fijos, si alguien me puede guiar en como hacerlo, ya he preguntado mucho de esto pero con todas las soluciones no e podido darle solucion.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    ejecutarListado = mysql.connection.cursor()
    ejecutarListado.execute('SELECT id, folio, lote, tabla, cajas, peso_neto FROM 
`registrocorte` WHERE `fecha` BETWEEN "20220920" AND "20220920";')
    datos = ejecutarListado.fetchall()
    resultadoLista = []
    for fila in datos:
            contenido = {'id': fila[0],
                     'folio': fila[1],
                     'lote': fila[2],
                     'tabla': fila[3],
                     'cajas': fila[4],
                     'peso_neto': fila[5]
                     }
            resultadoLista.append(contenido)
    return jsonify(resultadoLista)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, en que formato estan las columnas de fecha en tu base de datos? si puedes muestranos la estructura.

Comment: si se refiere al tipo de dato... esta como DATE

Comment: pues agradeceria un ejemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/ para poder darte una respuesta adecuada...

Comment: disculpa pero soy nuevo con esto y no se que dato pasarte esto es lo que tengo en la bd Nombre Tipo Cotejamiento Atributos Nulo Predeterminado Comentarios Extra
id Primaria int(11)   No Ninguna  AUTO_INCREMENT
folio varchar(6) utf8_bin  No Ninguna  
fecha date   No Ninguna  
lote varchar(20) utf8_bin  No Ninguna  
tabla int(5)   No Ninguna  
mayordomo varchar(20) utf8_bin  No Ninguna  
cajas int(10)   No Ninguna  
peso_tarima int(5)   No Ninguna  
peso_neto int(5)   No Ninguna

Comment: edita tu publicacion y agregalo

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. Dices que *funciona pero me da una serie de errores*. ¿Qué errores? ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente y dónde concretamente? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.